# jQuery serializeArray doesn't include the submit button that was clicked

Tags: jquery, serialization, w3c, form-submit

I have a form that has two buttons. One for saving a record and the other for cancelling the save procedure. I am using the `rails.js` *(a common AJAX/jQuery plug-in for those of you not in the know)*  javascript file that works with jQuery for unobtrusive javascript/ajax calls. When I send the form data over ajax, I want the name and value of the button I clicked to be submitted with the rest of the data so that I can make a decision on what to do based on which button was clicked.

The method in the `rails.js` file uses `.serializeArray()` for sending form data to the server. The problem is that this doesn't include the name/value pair of the button I've clicked. jQuery's website states that they do this on purpose (eventhough its my opinion that they should):

"The `.serializeArray()` method uses the standard W3C rules for [successful controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2) to determine which elements it should include; in particular the element cannot be disabled and must contain a name attribute. No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button."

How can they assume that a form WASN'T submitted using a button? This makes no sense and a wrong assumption I believe.

Under the W3C rules the button which was activated for the submission of a form is considered a **successful control**.

Since the developers of jQuery have decided to do this on purpose, can I assume that there is another method that **DOESN'T** exclude the activated button in a serialization?

**EDIT: Here is quick example of what my form might look like...**

```
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function(e) {
      // put your breakpoint here to look at e
      var x = 0;
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form">
    <input name="name" type="text"><br/>
    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Save"/>
    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Cancel"/>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: For anyone else finding this, the same problem exists with the `<button>` tag.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

> Is [there] another method that **DOESN'T** exclude the activated button in a serialization?

There is not, the behavior is based on the `submit` event *of the* `<form>`, not *of a button*, e.g. hitting enter or calling [`.submit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.submit) in JavaScript.  You're mixing 2 concepts here, a [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) or [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) may or may not have *anything* to do with a button click - it's just a separate event altogether, they're not connected.  These methods are at a higher level than that: you can serialize a form (or a subset of it) at any time for any reason.

You can however add the submit name/value pair like a normal form submitting from that button would, if you're submitting from a button for example:

```
$("#mySubmit").click(function() {
  var formData = $(this).closest('form').serializeArray();
  formData.push({ name: this.name, value: this.value });
  //now use formData, it includes the submit button
});
```

Comment: @Nick, thanks for the quick reply. I will have edit the `rails.js` (and possibly submit a patch) to make this work. I'll give this a shot.

Comment: @DJTripleThreat - I'm not that familiar with their code, is it possible to replace the event handler externally maybe? If you could post it I'll take a look

Comment: @Nick - check out the file on gh: http://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js. Look at the handler on lines 34 and 76. Is there a way to find out what button was clicked in the `event` object passed by `.submit(function(e){})`?

Comment: @DJTripleThreat - You can use `e.target` and pass that to `callRemote` is probably the easiest route, just have it accept an event parameter, use `e.target` inside, you can check `if($(e.target).is(":submit"))...`

Comment: hmm `e.target` is always the `HTMLFormElement` when coming from `.submit`. I don't see anything that determines which button was clicked. Chrome's Developer tools window says that `e` has a variable called `button` but its always undefined.

Comment: @DJTripleThreat - sorry for the confusion, you need to also attach the `click` handler to the submit button itself, like this: `$('form[data-remote] :submit').live('submit', function (e) { $(this.form).callRemote(e); return false; });`

Comment: @Nick, ok I realized that what you are showing me already exists in `rails.js` I removed `data-remote` from my buttons. I think I can get it to work if I add that attribute to my buttons.

Comment: @DJTripleThreat I handle this by appending the `name` and `value` of `document.activeElement` in the submit handler. I don't think it's perfectly cross-browser compatible, but this as part of a bigger abstraction would probably handle it well.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a fairly neat way to solve this:

```html
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="stuff" value="">
    <button type="submit" onclick="this.form.stuff.value=this.value" value="reset">reset</button>
    <button type="submit" onclick="this.form.stuff.value=this.value" value="delete">delete</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 8):

I use the following snippet, basically adds a hidden element with same name

```
 var form = $("form");
 $(":submit",form).click(function(){
            if($(this).attr('name')) {
                $(form).append(
                    $("<input type='hidden'>").attr( { 
                        name: $(this).attr('name'), 
                        value: $(this).attr('value') })
                );
            }
        });

 $(form).submit(function(){
     console.log($(this).serializeArray());
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

This solution is 'universal' as in it will handle all your input submits, passing each as a form variable on submission.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:submit').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            var formData = $(this).closest('form').serializeArray();
            formData.push({ name: $(this).attr('name'), value: $(this).val() });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You don't need the `each` call - just call `click` directly on the jquery object representing all input elements

Answer (score 1):

```
    var form = button.closest('form');
    var serialize = form.serialize();

    if (button.attr('name') !== undefined) {
        serialize += '&'+button.attr('name')+'=';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but if you don't want to bind an event to each button on your form, you can include this:

```js
$form.on('submit', function (e) {

    let formData = $(this).serializeArray();

    if (
        e.originalEvent
        && undefined !== e.originalEvent.submitter
        && undefined !== e.originalEvent.submitter.name
        && typeof e.originalEvent.submitter.name == "string"
        && e.originalEvent.submitter.name.length >= 1
        && undefined !== e.originalEvent.submitter.value
    ) {
        formData.push({
            name: e.originalEvent.submitter.name,
            value: e.originalEvent.submitter.value,
        });
    }

    // ...

});
```

Any submit button on your form that has a string name at least 1 character long and a defined value will be included in the `formData` array of objects.

Comment: You deserve a cookie