# serializeArray doesn't include submit-button value

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I got two submit buttons in a form. One that deletes the post, and one to edit it.

I want to display a fancybox with either the edit-form or a message saying that the user deleted the post. It's all decided by which button was pushed, with a "if(isset)"-sentence in edit.php. However I can't figure out how to get the value of the button within the serializeArray.. I tried with .click(function() instead, but that didn't send anything to the fancybox..

```
$("#form").bind("submit", function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type        : "POST",
                        cache       : false,
                        url         : "edit.php",
                        data        : $(this).serializeArray(),
                        success: function(data) {
                            $.fancybox(data);
                        }
                    });

                    return false;
                });
```

The form looks like this:

```
<form method='post' action='' id="form">
    <input type='submit' value='Edit' name='edit' />
    <input type='submit' value='Delete' name='delete' onClick="return slett('<?php echo $oppgave->name; ?>')"/>
    <input name='oppgaveID' type='hidden' value='<?php echo $oppgave->id; ?>' />
</form>
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the jQuery docs for `serialize()`:

> Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button. For a form element's value to be included in the serialized string, the element must have a name attribute. Data from file select elements is not serialized.

The rules for a "successful control" are defined here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2

Also check out [this Stack Overflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007942/jquery-serializearray-doesnt-include-the-submit-button-that-was-clicked/4007951#4007951) from Nick Craver.