# button click validation ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am using a button to submit a form with ajax..all works fine..But I need to check if the button is clicked in server side page..How to do it??Any help appreciated..Thanks..

```
<form>

some values
</form>
<input type="button" name="delete" id="delete" value="Delete"/><br/>
<input type="button" name="edit" id="edit" value="Edit"/><br/>
```

Script

```
$("#edit").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
     $("#form1").submit()
});

$("#form1").validate({
         debug: false,
   rules: {

    plid:"required",
       },
   messages: {

    plid: "Please select a pack name id..",
    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {

    $.ajax
   ({

type: "POST",
url: "aanew.php",
data: $('#form1').serialize(),
cache: false,

success: function(response) {
    $('#result1').html(response); 

        }
        });
        }

  });
```

I want to carry any attribute to check if my button is set... Thanks again..

The form value passes successfully, but I need to check the button status in another page..

Comment: Your button input-tags should be within the form-tags

Comment: create an hidden field with some value in the form and then check it server side

Comment: @RST I did that the values that passed is only 'plid' form value...the button are not seen..

Comment: @konnection I appreciate your response..Thanks.. I have two buttons..How can I use it to know if one button is clicked?

Comment: check my response its all there ;)

Comment: Do you want to recreate the button on the other page or just check its value and act upon it, or do you want to know whether or not the information was submitted through the form or by someone hacking your system? Or are you looking for something completely different?

Comment: @konnection ok so I have two buttons..how would a hidden field help..I am seralize the entire from.. so all values will pass..If I understood you right..thanks again

Comment: sorry the hidden field is just a precaution to check if user came from the form page, if you type directly in the url the page aanew.php it wont work because your hidden field was not set

Comment: @konnection The answer you gave helped me..thanks..But the alert(response) is displaying the entire page..What is the problem?? I have no idea of it..I am using only buttons here.. Any idea?? Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this field on the form, and the other inputs too like others have already pointed

```
<input type="hidden" name="check_click" value="1">
```

then in server side

```
if ((isset($_POST['check_click'])) && ($_POST['check_click'] == 1))
{
//The form was clicked
}
```

UPDATE:

if you want for each button

```
    if ((isset($_POST['check_click'])) && ($_POST['check_click'] == 1))
    {
    //The form was clicked

if (isset($_POST['delete']))
{
//delete has some value
}

if (isset($_POST['edit']))
{
//edit has some value
}

    }
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer..The problem is that in the server side I need to check the isset of both button, separately.. Any idea? If I use this I cannot identity which button was clicked..Thanks you :)

Comment: Thank you..It worked.. But I like to ask one thing..I am alerting the response here..It seems to alert the whole page in html..Any soultions??

Answer (score 1):

First of all your buttons in page should be in form tag like this

```
<form>

some values
<input type="button" name="delete" id="delete" value="Delete"/><br/>
<input type="button" name="edit" id="edit" value="Edit"/><br/>
</form>
```

then Simply just use isset function

```
if (isset($_POST['delete']))
```

or

```
if (isset($_POST['edit']))
```

whatever you click

Comment: Did you move the buttons inside the form?

Comment: @chadresh_cool yes I did.. Guess will check again thank you :)

Comment: ok also just alert your serialize string before sending ajax post see what you get in alert just to debug the code

Comment: For some reason it is not working..But I wanted to ask when I try to alert the response from ajax, I get the whole ajax called page in html.. Any idea?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can insert into the form tag two submit buttons with different values. And on server side check - which one has come. This approach is also make adding Ajax functionality easier - because you can now add the same callback on this two buttons/

Comment: Thank you.. When I used submit button,I didn't get the desired result..When I alert I get the whole page..

Comment: Maybe this will give you a clue about what you can do - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007942/jquery-serializearray-doesnt-include-the-submit-button-that-was-clicked