# jquery ui confirmation dialog not working

Tags: php, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, confirm

I have a series of checkboxes that correspond to entries, and a delete all button that I have attached a jquery ui modal confirm. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/BxdWc/. The issue is that, it does not submit the form (*is not processed by php*) after hitting yes in the confirmation dialog. The php code is include at the top of the page, but I am fairly certain it has nothing to do with this, as without the modal the code processes, and deletes the checked entries properly.

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $("#dialog-confirm-multiple").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        width: 300,
        modal: true,
        show: {
            effect: "bounce",
            duration: 100
        },
        hide: "drop",
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function () {
                $("#confirm").submit();
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "No": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
    $("#doDelete").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#dialog-confirm-multiple").dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form post="self.php" id="confirm">
<!-- some inputs .etc -->
<input name="doDelete" type="submit" id="doDelete" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
</form>
```

Comment: Does it not submit or does it just not `POST` the data?

Comment: Does not post, page reloads after click. Weird tho, because without the js, it works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your PHP is checking for which button is clicked. jQuery does not include the buttons when you submit a form via `$('#confirm').submit();`. The browser will only include the buttons in the submission if the button was actually clicked.

There are a couple ways to get the button name/value pair to be included in the submission.

You can use `$('form').serializeArray();` and push the doDelete/Delete pair as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007942/jquery-serializearray-doesnt-include-the-submit-button-that-was-clicked)

Or you might be able to get away with doing something like this. Notice the click of the delete button is called a second time. The button click event checks if it was initiated via a trigger (aka the dialog). The second time around, it will not be prevented from being submitted.

```
$(function () {
    $("#dialog-confirm-multiple").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        width: 300,
        modal: true,
        show: {
            effect: "bounce",
            duration: 100
        },
        hide: "drop",
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                $("#doDelete").click();
            },
            "No": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
    $("#doDelete").click(function (e,ui) {
        if(e.originalEvent) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#dialog-confirm-multiple").dialog('open');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

The fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BxdWc/12/)

Comment: It seems that jQuery `isTrigger` is [not ready for prime time](https://github.com/jquery/api.jquery.com/issues/319).  I think this still works if you replace `!e.isTrigger` with `e.originalEvent`.

Comment: Good catch! I've updated the snippet and the fiddle to use originalEvent rather than isTrigger. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I modified this a little bit so that it can work when you denote the confirm button with a class rather than an id.  I'm a javascript novice so beware!  Feel free to improve on this.

```
$(function () {
    $("input.doDelete").click(function (e,ui) {
        var button = $(e.target);
        $("#dialog-confirm-multiple").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            width: 300,
            modal: true,
            show: {
                effect: "bounce",
                duration: 100
            },
            hide: "drop",
            buttons: {
                "Yes": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    button.click();
                },
                "No": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        if(e.originalEvent) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#dialog-confirm-multiple").dialog('open');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```