# How to include submit button name and values on form Serialize() ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I have trouble, my code doesn't work, because my server script side need a name from the submit button. I'm using Ajax method, and I'm using data: serialize, when I have Click on Submit, it doesn't work. Here is my JavaScript code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#buy_product').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var submitData = $('#buy_product').serialize();
            submitData.push({ name: this.name, value: this.value });
        $('.loading').html('{{HTML::image('img/ajax-loader.gif')}}');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: submitData,
            url: "{{URL::base()}}/products/view/{{$products->id}}/{{Str::slug($products->name_product, '_')}}",
            success: function(msg){
                $('#qty').val(''); 
                $('.loading').html(msg);
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

If you have clue, please tell me, I'll be glad.

---

My button is like this:

```
<input name="update" id="update" type="submit" value="update">

<input name="empty" id="empty" type="submit" value="empty">
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can't do that but you can use a hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" name="any_name" value="any_value" />
```

Comment: this might help too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007942/jquery-serializearray-doesnt-include-the-submit-button-that-was-clicked

Comment: `<input name="update" id="update" type="submit" value="update">` `<input name="empty" id="empty" type="submit" value="empty">`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Java Script Code:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        $(function(){
            $('#form').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var submitData = $('#form').serialize();
                var btnName = $('#submit').attr('name');
                var btnVal = $('#submit').val();
                var btn = '&'+btnName+'='+btnVal;
                submitData += btn;
                alert(submitData);                

            }); 
        }); 
</script>
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<form action="" id="form" type='post'>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value='Scott'/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value='POST'/>
</form>
```

**or use:**

```
var submitData = $('#buy_product').serialize();
submitData += '&btnName=' +  $('#your_submitbtn_id').attr('name') + '&btnValue='+ $('##your_submitbtn_id').attr('value');
```