# how to add $_POST['submit'] in ajax jquery or what is the best way to do this..?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

index.php

```
<form id="myForm" action="test2.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Print 1" name="submit" id="submit">
    <input type="submit" value="Print 2" name="submit2" id="submit2">
</form> 
<div id="ack"></div>
```

here's my script

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/login_script.js"></script>
```

test2.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
echo "1"; // i want to show this everytime i click submit (not working)
}          // or what is the proper way to do this..

if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
echo "2"; // i want to show this everytime i click submit2 (not working)
}         // or what is the proper way to do this..
?>
```

login_script.js

```
$("#submit, #submit2").click( function() {
  $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"),
         $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),

         function(data) {
                $("#ack").empty();
                $("#ack").html(data);
    });


$("#myForm").submit( function() {
   return false;    
});
});
```

if i remove the if(isset($_POST['submit'])).... its working...
so what is the proper way to do this..? 
sorry im noob in ajax and jquery

Comment: Make sure the `name=` of your second input is also `submit2`

Comment: still not working sir, i think the problem there is if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){...? do you have any idea?

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007942/jquery-serializearray-doesnt-include-the-submit-button-that-was-clicked?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this:

```
$("#submit, #submit2").click( function() {
        var formData = $(this).closest('form').serializeArray();
          formData.push({ name: this.name, value: this.value });
      $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"),formData,


             function(data) {
                    $("#ack").empty();
                    $("#ack").html(data);
        });


    $("#myForm").submit( function() {
       return false;    
    });
    });
```

Comment: thank you  sir :) because i also passing a data like this $username = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["name"] ); i used your codes...

Answer (score 2):

No, you have to realize that `<input type="submit"` and `<button> submit` is not included in `.serializeArray()`, you'll have to just build the data object to be passed:

```
    $("#submit, #submit2").click( function() {
        var data = null;
        if($(this).attr('id') == 'submit') {
            values = {'submit': true};
        } else {
            values = {'submit2': true};
        }

            $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), values,

         function(data) {
                $("#ack").empty();
                $("#ack").html(data);
    });
});
```

[Sample Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/8lFmlN)

Comment: thank you sir for this `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {` but i also want to pass data like this `mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["name"] ); and i found the answer above.. thank you for your time.. :)

Comment: can i ask one more question? @Ghost? because i have 3 days before i can ask question again.

Comment: @PauloB.DelaCruz yes and what is it?

Comment: its not related,sometimes my external css is not reading my new codes,sometimes working ,sometimes not? and i found that when i press f12 and look at my css codes , still the same,the old code is still there, even i change it and save.

Comment: @PauloB.DelaCruz try to clear cookies, cache, etc. of the browser, and use a hard refresh on the browser

Comment: ah hard refresh, my chrome has no hard refresh.. hehe thank you for your time sir..

Comment: @PauloB.DelaCruz i think its ctrl + F5 or ctrl + shift + F5 not sure though

Comment: @PauloB.DelaCruz sure tol no prob

Comment: pinoy karin pala whahha

Answer (score 0):

Yes I just try it and below code is working for me please check.

index.php

```
<form id="myForm" action="test2.php" method="POST">
<input type="submit" value="Print 1" name="submit" id="submit">
<input type="submit" value="Print 2" name="submit2" id="submit2">
</form> 
<div id="ack"></div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#submit, #submit2").click( function() {
   $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"),
      $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
       function(data) {
            $("#ack").empty();
            $("#ack").html(data);
});
$("#myForm").submit( function() {
return false;    
});
});
</script>
```

test.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){  
echo "1"; // i want to show this everytime i click submit (not working)
}          // or what is the proper way to do this..
if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
echo "2"; // i want to show this everytime i click submit2 (not working)
}         // or what is the proper way to do this..
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

In the post it user name instead of the ID. Please try code below hope it will help you.

```
<form id="myForm" action="test2.php" method="POST">
<input type="submit" value="Print 1" name="submit" id="submit">
<input type="submit" value="Print 2" name="submit2" id="submit2">
</form>
```