# jQuery serializeArray fails

Tags: jquery, serialization

Consider the following:

PHP:

```
<form id="f-submit" method="post" action="">

    <button class="btn-submit" name="update" type="submit">APPROUVE</button>

</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$("button.btn-submit").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var formData = $("#f-submit").serializeArray();
    formData.push({actiontype: "delete"});

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/submit_comment.php",
        data: formData
    }).done(function(data) {

        alert(data);

    }).fail(function(data) {

        alert('Ajax failed.');

    });
});
```

submit_comment.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['actiontype'])) {

    echo 'found';

} else {

    echo 'not found';

}
```

For some reason, i always get 'not found'.

But, when I'm sending the data without serializing, like so,

```
var formData = ({actiontype: "delete"});
```

It works!!!

So the problem must be on the serializeArray(), but what is it? I'm going crazy whith this one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this sytax:

```
formData.push({name: 'actiontype', value: delete});
```

Answer (score 0):

`serializeArray()`produces an object composed by names and values.
Have you tried to debug `var formData = $("#f-submit").serializeArray();`? In your case it should produce no names/values pairs because:

> Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button. For a form element's value to be included in the serialized string, the element must have a name attribute. Data from file select elements is not serialized. [jQuery doc](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

Thus you have to add a different input from the submit one. Let's check this smart solution: [jQuery serializeArray doesn't include the submit button that was clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007942/jquery-serializearray-doesnt-include-the-submit-button-that-was-clicked/4007951#4007951)