# (button || input) type=submit - missing value in $_POST variable in jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have login form where are two buttons - "login" and "forgot password?" And I need to check what button user clicked.

```
<form id="loginForm">
<div class="login-error" id="login-error"></div>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email">
<input type="password" id="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="Forgot password?">Forgot password?</button>
</form>
```

var_dump($_POST) says:

```
array(2) { ["email"]=> string(0) "" ["password"]=> string(0) "" }
```

I am trying both ways (input type=submit and button type=submit) but none of them send the "submit" value.

(I am using jquery ajax)

```
 $("#loginForm").click(function(){
    /* Stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault();

    /* Get some values from elements on the page: */
    var values = $(this).serialize();

    /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
    $.ajax({
        url: "login.php", /* here is echo var_dump($_POST); */
        type: "post",
        data: values,
        success: function(data){
            $("#login-error").html(data);
        },
        error:function(){
            $("#result").html('There is error while submit');
        }
    });
});
```

Please do you know where the problem can be? I know, there are lot of threads about value of button but nothing works for me. I also tried this example:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_button_value2

Comment: value attribute is going to show the name of the button on your web page?Isn't it? It's not treated as value like other fields have. But you can do it

Comment: No, on a button the value attribute is used in a traditional manner as in, for passing a value. This is because buttons are used in the traditional manner <button>button text</button>

Comment: Just in case you haven't read this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007942/jquery-serializearray-doesnt-include-the-submit-button-that-was-clicked

Comment: or this..http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: or this..http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: Beware, setting `name="submit"` you are overwriting default DOM `submit()` method. That's said, i'm quite sure this question is a dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007942/jquery-serializearray-doesnt-include-the-submit-button-that-was-clicked  BTW, seems more relevant to use the `submit` event of the FORM, not the click one. Do you really want to send data to server if e.g `email` is clicked???

Comment: Hello A. Wolff, thank you for your reply. Okay, I edited it this way:

`<input type="submit" name="action" value="Login">
<button type="submit" name="action" value="Forgot password?">Forgot password?</button>`

And jquery to:
`$("#loginForm").submit(function(event) {`

So form is now sending only on click to the buttons. But `$_POST['action']` is still not set in both ways (input and button). I will check serialize suggestions.

Comment: @JackDavis In fact, you could handle it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/26gdp7en/  But imho, you'd have better to target a different server script regarding the request is for login or 'forgot password'  http://jsfiddle.net/26gdp7en/1/

Comment: @A.Wolff Wolff Thank you very much, this is working well! Can you please post it as answer so I can accept it as solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to do it, concatening data string with specific clicked button name attribute:

HTML:

```
<form id="loginForm">
    <div class="login-error" id="login-error"></div>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
    <button type="button" name="login" class="submit">Login</button>
    <button type="button" name="forgot" class="submit">Forgot password?</button>
</form>
```

JQ:

```
$("#loginForm").on('click', '.submit', function (event) {

    /* Stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault();

    /* Get some values from elements on the page: */
    var values = $(this).closest('form').serialize() + '&' + this.name;
    console.log(values);
    /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
    $.ajax({
        url: "login.php",
        /* here is echo var_dump($_POST); */
        type: "post",
        data: values,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#login-error").html(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            $("#result").html('There is error while submit');
        }
    });
});
```

But better would be to target specific server side script depending which button is clicked, e.g:

HTML:

```
<form id="loginForm">
    <div class="login-error" id="login-error"></div>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
    <button type="button" name="login" class="submit" data-url="login.php">Login</button>
    <button type="button" name="forgot" class="submit" data-url="forgot.php">Forgot password?</button>
</form>
```

JQ:

```
$("#loginForm").on('click', '.submit', function (event) {

    /* Stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault();

    /* Get some values from elements on the page: */
    var values = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
    /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).data('url'),
        /* here is echo var_dump($_POST); */
        type: "post",
        data: values,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#login-error").html(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            $("#result").html('There is error while submit');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

The .serializeArray() or .serialize() method uses the standard W3C rules for successful controls to determine which elements it should include; in particular the element cannot be disabled and must contain a name attribute. No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button. Data from file select elements is not serialized.

Refer..

http://api.jquery.com/serialize

http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray

[jQuery serializeArray doesn't include the submit button that was clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007942/jquery-serializearray-doesnt-include-the-submit-button-that-was-clicked)

Answer (score 2):

It will be a lot easier to check if you name the submit input and the button differently.

You currently have this set up like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="Forgot password?">Forgot password?</button>
```

Try changing the name of the button to something like:

```
name="forgot"
```

then you can run a check on it such as

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    stuff here

}
```

and a separate check for

```
if (isset($_POST['forgot'])){

    stuff here

}
```

Comment: The problem is that neither button value ever makes it to the server.

Comment: Hello, thanks but there is other problem. Variable $_POST['submit'] is not set in any way so when I rename it to any other, it will not be set also.

Comment: oh right.  sorry about that.   See the suggestions regarding `.serializeArray() or .serialize() ` in the other answer.  I was only addressing one small aspect.

Answer (score 0):

If there is not event in function then it will not prevent the submit function and by default get will be called and and $_POST will be empty for sure
Change

```
 $("#loginForm").click(function(){
        /* Stop form from submitting normally */
        event.preventDefault();
```

To

```
$("#loginForm").click(function(event){
    /* Stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault();
```

Make one more change

```
data: values,
```

To

```
data:$("#loginForm").serialize(),
```

Remove one submit type there should be only one submit type make it type of button and call onbutton click functiuon to submit via ajax it will work same as submit.

Comment: This is a good point regarding Firefox not using `window.event` model but i'm not sure how this answers question?!

Comment: Hello, thanks but the result is the same. Should there be a difference in this case?