# Retrieve the name of the submit button in a form using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am working with PHP and jQuery. I have 2 files

`test.php`

```html
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".form-register").submit(function (e) {

            var form_data = $(this).serialize();

            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "test2.php",
                data: form_data,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(){
                    alert(form_data);
                }

            });
        });


    });
</script>

<form class="form-register">
    <input name="email" type="text"/>
    <input name="name" type="text"/>
    <input type="submit" name="register"/>
</form>
```

and the second file is `test2.php`:

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['register'])){
    echo json_encode('Message from test2.php');
}else{
    echo json_encode('post no received');
}
```

It seems like I am unable to retrieve `$_POST['register']` because when I check `alert(form_data);` only the `email` and the `name` are displayed.

Is there anyway for me to get `$_POST['register']`?

Comment: Try adding a value attribute to it.

Comment: <input type="submit" name="register" value="register" /> use this.. and check you can solve your issue.. no need to do anything.

Comment: Please check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007942/jquery-serializearray-doesnt-include-the-submit-button-that-was-clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither `.serialize()` nor `.serializeArray()` will serialize the submit button value.

> [.serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)
>
> ...No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button.
>
> [.serializeArray()](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)
>
> ...No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button.

Only [successful controls](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2) are serialized.

The input submit element is actually a successful control, but as mentioned above since the form is not submitted using the submit button, the input submit value attribute will not be included by jquery serialization.

If you want to use `.serializeArray()` just add the input submit elements name and value attribute values as an object to the serialized array like so.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".form-register").submit(function (e) {

    var form_data = $(this).serializeArray();
    var $submit = $(this).find('input[type="submit"]');
    form_data.push({name: $submit.prop("name"), value: $submit.val()});
    console.log(form_data);
    
    // do your ajax request here...
    
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-register">
  <input name="email" type="text"/>
  <input name="name" type="text"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="register"/>
</form>
```

If you want to use `.serialize()` just add the values of the value and name attributes of the submit element to the text string created by the `.serialize()` method. Be careful, the string needs to be URL-encoded.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".form-register").submit(function (e) {

    var form_data = $(this).serialize();
    var $submit = $(this).find('input[type="submit"]');
    form_data = form_data + "&" + $submit.prop("name") + "=" + $submit.val();
    console.log(form_data);

    // do your ajax request here...

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-register">
  <input name="email" type="text"/>
  <input name="name" type="text"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="register"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks guy. But in my initial code, when I replace the second line of the file `test2.php` (`if(isset($_POST['register'])){`) by (`if(!empty($_POST)){`), the `if condition` of the test2.php returns true even if the input fields were empty while submitting the form. Is there anyway to solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

Add value attribute to submit button and use `$('form').serializeArray()` . Try:

```
$(".form-register").submit(function (e) {
  var formData = $(this).serializeArray();
  var name = $(this).find("input[type=submit]").attr("name");
  var value = $(this).find("input[type=submit]").val();
  formData.push({ name: name, value: value });
  //now use formData, it includes the submit button
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "test2.php",
     data: formData,
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(){
         alert(form_data);
     }
  }); 
});
```

Comment: `this` is referring to the form

Comment: Thanks guys. But in my initial code, when I replace the second line of the file `test2.php` (`if(isset($_POST['register'])){`) by (`if(!empty($_POST)){`), the `if condition` of the test2.php returns true even if the input fields were empty while submitting the form. Is there anyway to solve it ?