# Send button value by post request via jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, serialization

My code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
<button id="test" value="123" name="test" >ok</button>
</form>

<script>


 $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#test").click(function() {
                   var combinedData = $("#test").serialize();
                 $.post(
                        "element_submit.php",
                        combinedData
                 ).done(function(data) {
                        //alert("Successfully submitted!");
                        $("#result").html(data);
                 }).fail(function () {
                          //alert("Error submitting forms!");
                 })
          });
        });

</script>



<div id="result" ></div>
```

The **element_submit.php** file

```
<?php 

//just to test it should output in the #result div 
echo $_POST['test'];

?>
```

What I am trying to do is submit the  with the **value="attribute"** so the data is serialized and send the post request, it's not like a  submit when user insert a value and submit,What I need is to get the value attribute and submit to the php, this code is only for To simplify and illustrate what I am trying to do, because in this page I have the following buttons with ids #follow #unfollow so I need a way to get the button value to make the user follow and unfollow.

Comment: Please refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007942/jquery-serializearray-doesnt-include-the-submit-button-that-was-clicked

Comment: Thanks, It's  very usefull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to serialize the form - not the elements within it .You can also have the triggering button outside the form which will prevent hte form from submitting on the button click.

```
<form id="testForm">
   <input type="hidden" name="testInput" value="123"/>
</form>

 <button name="test" id="testButton">submit</button>
...

<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#testButton").click(function() {
                   var combinedData = $("#testForm").serialize();...
```

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#testButton").click(function() {
        var combinedData = $("#testForm").serialize();
         console.log(combinedData);
      })
   })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="testForm">
   <input type="hidden" value="123" name="testinput"/>
</form>
<button  id="testButton">Click</button>
```

Comment: what do you get if you console.log(combinedData ); before you try the post?

Comment: Output all blank

Comment: I need the button inside the form because on click the user will follow or unfollow so the element clicked is what will be send via post

Comment: answer updated to have an input in the form -you can have that as a hidden value - so the triggering button does not need to be in the form - and if you don't want to see it have the type = hidden - this then allwosthe ajax form submission and I have put a console ,log in ther to show the outcome - it works

Comment: output the form it's works but the problem is that I need the button inside the form because my php checks in data base if user is following other if so it outputs to the button with id=#following , etc I will see what I can implement if the form don't break the css , thanks for the alternative solution

Answer (score 1):

Straight JS might help you out.  Include a function that sends the id and get the value of that id.  Then just send a regular post of the value without serialize... easier.

```
<script>
function fetchButtonValue(theId){
var p = document.getElementById(theId).value;
alert (p);
}
</script>

<button id="myFormBtn" value ="woo" 
onclick="fetchButtonValue(this.id)">My Button</button>
```

this works...

You could also put a class on the button let's say class="followBTN" then on a click you could just snag the value by $(this).val()  I'd use this method if I had more than one button per page.